# How to increase font size of some part of string in android?

Tags: android

I want increase font size of some part of the string before set to text view.
Means My string is "Hello Stack over flow". Then I want font size of over is larger than other words and its bold.

Comment: You can use Html.fromHtml().

Comment: You can use a Spannable String

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9842023/1937802

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do something like below,

```
 String str="<small>Hello Stack</small><big>Over</big>flow";
 textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(str));
```

Comment: anywhere to see the variation of sizes? bigger? biggest?

Comment: worst solution. NVA is absolutely right

Answer (score 6):

You can use a `SpannableString`

Example :

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
String string= "Hello";
String title="MyTitle";
SpannableString ss1=  new SpannableString(string);
ss1.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2f), 0, ss1.length(), 0);
tv.append(ss1);
tv.append(title);
setContentView(tv);
```

Snap

[image]

You may also check

[Using size HTML attribute in TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247113/using-html-in-textview)

Searching for supported html tags

http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html

http://bigknol.com/android-supported-html-tags-textview-string/

Answer (score 0):

you can use html string to make some part bold for example

```
private String getHtmlText(String boldString,String restString){

    String htmlString = "<b>" +boldString +"</b> "  + restString;

    return htmlString;
}
```

and then setText using Html.fromHtml(htmlString) like

```
  yourTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getHtmlText(textBold,textNormal)));
```