# How to change textsize of a word in a string Android?

Tags: android, string-formatting

I have a String which should shows my value out of a total value, Like 2/5 ,But what i want to do is show it as 2 or the number before the "/" is of a comparatively larger size then the number after the "/" . This is what i have tried so far, and it has no effect.

```
    SpannableString ss1=  new SpannableString(String.valueOf(connectedDevices + "/" + totalDevices));
    ss1.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2f), 0,1, 0); // set size
    mData.get(0).setCurrentCount(String.valueOf(ss1) );
    notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I want the size of connectedDevices to be N (e.g. N=3) times of the size of totalDevices. How can I format this string?

The difference from the link this question is marked as duplicate is that I am storing this text in a string or in any variable and then using it later on through the adapter of a recyclerview.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to increase font size of some part of string in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22398641/how-to-increase-font-size-of-some-part-of-string-in-android)

Comment: The answer by Raghunandan should be what you're looking for

Comment: The `String.valueOf(ss1)` call is essentially stripping the span you've set on the `SpannableString`. Change your `setCurrentCount()` method, and the underlying field, to handle a `SpannableString`, or something more generic, like `CharSequence`.

Comment: @MikeM. I do get your point but i dont understand how to implement that can you please give me an example ? setCurrentCount() sets a String value and how should i handle a SpannableString with CharSequence ?

Comment: I'm assuming that `mData` is a `List` of some data type that you've written. If so, then you just need to change the current count field in that data class to `CharSequence`, instead of `String`, and similarly for the getter and setter methods' parameters. If, at some point, you do need a flat `String`, you would convert it then; e.g., with `toString()`, or `String.valueOf()`.

Comment: @MikeM. Perfect. Thankyou so much if you can put that as an answer can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A plain `String` does not hold any span formatting information, so the `String.valueOf(ss1)` call is basically undoing the formatting you've done with the `SpannableString` and the `RelativeSizeSpan`.

To preserve that formatting, change the type of the relevant field, as well as the parameter types on any corresponding methods, to `CharSequence`, which is the base `interface` that pretty much all textual data types implement. You would then pass that `SpannableString` directly to `setCurrentCount()`, instead of first converting it to a `String`.

If, at some point, you do need a flat `String`, you can convert it then; e.g., with `toString()` or `String.valueOf()`.