# Changing the font of String

Tags: java, android

I am trying to change the font size of string which is displaying on textview.
remember there are two string which are displaying on same textview.I want different font size 
for both string.

```
String name = shopsArrayList.get(position);
String address = shopsAddress.get(position);
```

i tried this but it is done on both string,

```
tv.setText(name.toUpperCase() + "\r\n" + address);
tv.setPadding(25, 15, 0, 0);
tv.setTextSize(25);
```

please help!!!

Comment: So what is the question? Change the font size before you display, accordingly?

Comment: thank you for the quick response.i want to display different font size at same textview yes you can change the font size  before the display

Comment: this will help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529068/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-styles-inside-a-textview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that easily using [`SpannableString`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html).

See this example:

```
String str= "Hello World";
SpannableString spannable=  new SpannableString(str);
spannable.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.5f), 0, 5, 0); //size
spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.CYAN), 0, 5, 0);//Color
TextView txtview= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
txtview.setText(spannable);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: spannable.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.5f), 0, 5, 0); //size   can you plz describe the above function or share a link

Comment: [check this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/RelativeSizeSpan.html) @user3767207

Comment: And [this](http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/android_textview_rich_text_spannablestring) @user3767207 :)

Comment: the above code is not working, i can't increase or decrease the size of font please help....

Comment: Did you try 2f or 3f? @user3767207

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9842023/1777090). what's issue? @user3767207 This should work.

Comment: yes, the application crashes when i increase it...and with this above when i scroll the textview the application crashes

Comment: where i can see crash time logcat? the font is done but after the scroll application is crashed. thankyou for font help

Comment: Welcome. you can see the crash time exception in logcat. Search for android view logcat in google if you don't already know :) happy coding.

Comment: type:E 06-23 11:14:4 pid:1008 crash time logcat

Answer (score 1):

Try to using Html format, Something like this:

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<p style='font-family: serif;'>Description here</p><br><p style='font-family: Times;'>Blah Blah Blah</p>", Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
    } else {
        myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<p style='font-family: serif;'>Description here</p><br><p style='font-family: Times;'>Blah Blah Blah</p>"));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the second string into a Span that allows you to change the style of the text, such as a TextAppearanceSpan.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/TextAppearanceSpan.html

Answer (score 0):

You can first set style for that

```
<style name="firstStyle">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/regular_text</item>
</style>
<style name="secondStyle">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/bullet_text</item>
</style>
```

Then you have to make a single string from those two string of yours and specify the length of your string where you need to apply for effect.

```
SpannableString span = new SpannableString(myString);

span.setSpan(new TextAppearanceSpan(getContext(), R.style.firstStyle),0,15, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
span.setSpan(new TextAppearanceSpan(getContext(), R.style.secondStyle),16,30, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

tv.setText(span, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

A dynamic way to acheive the same

```
    String name = shopsArrayList.get(position);
    String address = shopsAddress.get(position);

    int nameLength = name.length();
    int addressLength = address.length();
    Spannable span = new SpannableString(name+address);
    span.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD),0, nameLength,Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    span.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC),nameLength+1, addressLength,Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

now set the text to textview

```
textView.setText(span);
```