# How to apply .setBackgroundColor to a selected portion of textview?

Tags: android, textview

I have code that  sets the background of  textview  green. 
If 1st textview tv1=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz and I just want to select  "mnopqrst" by touching and and set its background green. How to do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851781/spannablestring-is-it-possible-to-apply-two-or-more-relativesizespans

Comment: i an less than a beginner in Stackoverflow. Please help me sorting out.